# Filtering out login logs from Gitlab production_json.log with jq

Tags: jq, gitlab-omnibus

I'm trying to filter out login events from the `production_json.log` of a Omnibus GitLab server.

Thus JSON elements that i want to filter look like this:

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/users/sign_in",
  "format": "html",
  "controller": "SessionsController",
  "action": "create",
  "status": 302,
  "duration": 146.22,
  "view": 0,
  "db": 16.64,
  "location": "https://maschm.ddnss.de/",
  "time": "2021-01-05T11:44:30.180Z",
  "params": [
    {
      "key": "utf8",
      "value": "✓"
    },
    {
      "key": "authenticity_token",
      "value": "[FILTERED]"
    },
    {
      "key": "user",
      "value": {
        "login": "root",
        "password": "[FILTERED]",
        "remember_me": "0"
      }
    }
  ],
  "remote_ip": "46.86.21.18",
  "user_id": 1,
  "username": "root",
  "ua": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.2 Safari/605.1.15",
  "queue_duration": 7.3,
  "correlation_id": "JtnY93e2ti8"
}
```

I only want output for such elements.

`jq` is new to me. I'm using this command now:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log | 
jq --unbuffered '
   if .remote_ip != null and .method == "POST" and
      .path == "/users/sign_in" and .action == "create"
   then
      .ua + " " + .remote_ip else ""
   end
'
```

The output looks like this:

```
""
""
""
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.2 Safari/605.1.15 46.86.21.18"
""
""
""
""
""
""
```

I have two questions:

1. How can i avoid the `""` output (there should be no output for other JSON elements)?
2. Is `if` the correct `jq` statement for filtering?

Comment: You might want `--raw-output`/`-r` so the output is just text instead of JSON string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `empty` instead of `""` to solve the problem, but using `select()` to filter out unwanted stream elements is a cleaner solution.

```sh
jq --unbuffered '
   select(
      .remote_ip != null and
      .method == "POST" and
      .path == "/users/sign_in" and
      .action == "create"
   ) |
   .ua + " " + .remote_ip
'
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. `sudo tail -f /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log | jq --raw-output --unbuffered 'select(.remote_ip != null and .method == "POST" and .path == "/users/sign_in" and .action == "create") |   .ua + " " + .remote_ip'` is working perfectly.